# Updating a Property w/ 2013 REST Api

Tags: javascript, 2013, web-services, rest

I have a SharePoint Hosted App that is successfully able to add Read and Create files on the Host site (using the REST API and `SP.RequestExecutor`). Now I am trying to figure out how to update properties. Specifically the `SP.View.jsLink` property.

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj246122.aspx) I should be able to POST to the following url to set it?  What is the request body supposed to look like? Do I have to then post to the [update method on the view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj245633.aspx) to save it?

```
http://<sitecollection>/<site>/_api/web/lists(listid)/Views(viewid)/jsLink
```

Posting to the above url (experimenting w/ different request body values), comes back 200, but doesn't update the property. Then I tried performing a **PATCH** on the entire `SP.View` object, according to [Microsoft's example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp142386.aspx#bk_performCRUD).  The **PATCH** (and **MERGE** and **PUT**) throws the following error.

```
{"error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"An entry without a type name was found, but no expected type was specified. To allow entries without type information, the expected type must also be specified when the model is specified."}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this working using JSOM. I'm not happy about it though. It feels wierd to mix REST with JSOM.

```
//Initilize JSOM contexts inside constructor
var DataService = function(appUrl, hostUrl) {
    var self = this;
    //Some other stuff not related to this...

    self.appContext = new SP.ClientContext(appUrl);
    var factory = new SP.ProxyWebRequestExecutorFactory(appUrl);
    self.appContext.set_webRequestExecutorFactory(factory);
    self.hostContext = new SP.AppContextSite(self.appContext, hostUrl);
};

//Update jsLink
DataService.prototype.setJsLink = function(listTitle, viewTitle, templateName) {
    var self = this,
        deferred = new $.Deferred(),
        web = self.hostContext.get_web(),
        view = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle).get_views().getByTitle(viewTitle);

    view.set_jsLink("~site/SiteAssets/" + templateName);
    view.update();
    self.appContext.executeQueryAsync(deferred.resolve, deferred.reject);

    return deferred;
};
```

Don't forget to give your app permissions in the AppManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was to simply include the `__metadata` property as part of the PATCH request. So, instead of just sending the POST data:

```
{
    Id: 1,
    Title: "Something"
}
```

we had to send:

```
{
    Id: 1,
    Title: "Something",
    __metadata: {
        type: "SP.Data.NameOfOurObject"
    }
}
```

We also included the `etag`, `id` and `uri` portions of the metadata, but I do not believe those are required for the request to be successful.

Answer (score 0):

In order to update `JSLink` property of a View, the following conditions must to be met:

- proper View resource endpoint url, for example:
  `/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('listTitle')/views/getbytitle('viewTitle')`
- entity type for View resource set to : `'__metadata': {'type': 'SP.View'}`

### How to update List View using SharePoint 2013 REST

```
function postJson(endpointUri,payload,isUpdate, success, error) 
{
    var headers = {};
    headers["Accept"] = "application/json;odata=verbose";
    headers["X-RequestDigest"] = $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val();
    if(isUpdate) {
       headers["X-HTTP-Method"] = "MERGE";
       headers["If-Match"] = "*";
    }   

    $.ajax({       
       url: endpointUri,   
       type: "POST",   
       processData: false,  
       data: JSON.stringify(payload),
       contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
       headers: headers, 
       success: success,
       error: error
    });
}



function updateView(webUrl,listTitle,viewTitle,viewProperties, success,failure)
{
    //construct View resource endpoint url
    var viewUri =  webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')/views/getbytitle('" + viewTitle + "')";
    //prepare View resource payload
    var viewPayload = {
       '__metadata': {'type': 'SP.View'}
    };
    for(var prop in viewProperties){
         viewPayload[prop] = viewProperties[prop];
    }

    postJson(viewUri,viewPayload,true,
       function(data){
          success(); 
        },
       failure);
}
```

Gist: [updateView.js](https://gist.github.com/vgrem/34b6e126949dfeda908a)

**Usage**

The following example demonstrates how to update `JSLink` property for a View using SharePoint REST:

```
var viewProperties = {'JSLink':'hierarchytaskslistex.js'};

updateView(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,'Tasks','All Tasks',viewProperties,printInfo,logError);
function printInfo(view)
{
    console.log('View has been updated');
}
function logError(error){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
}
```