# Create Web Property in Web Property Bag in SharePoint Site using REST API

Tags: 2013, javascript, rest

I want to add one Web Property to sharepoint sub site using REST API.

Is it possible or feasible using REST API?

Comment: What web property?

Comment: I want to add one property bag in SPWeb. so that I can access it from SPWeb.Properties.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be possible using REST api. You'll have to do it with JSOM. Multiple instances: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/65628/updating-a-property-w-2013-rest-api, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18249460/sharepoint-2013-property-bag-crud-using-jquery-rest-api-and-csom-ecmascript, http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/133924/set-value-in-web-property-bag-using-rest-api.